# Nextjs: set priority for useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

This is my `_app.tsx`

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(1)
}, []);
```

And this is my `index.tsx`

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(2)
}, []);
```

So, in my console print `21`

But I want to print `12`

How can I set priority for `useEffect` for run `_app` first?

Comment: Could you give a backstory about why you need it?

Comment: @NickVu  want to fetch data1 in `_app` and fetch data2 in `index`

Comment: you can add data dependencies to `index.tsx` useEffect, useEffect(() =>{console.log(2)}, [appData]);. And in `_app.tsx`, you can have `useEffect(() => {//fetch appData})`

Comment: What @NickVu said. The correct way to control order for effects is to have their dependencies correctly set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

You can't set priority across components.

### Long Answer

Disregarding why someone would need control over the priority of `useEffect` across components in the first place, the order at which `useEffect` are being run by different component, cannot be controlled on our end. Following [this article](https://localcoder.org/whats-useeffect-execution-order-and-its-internal-clean-up-logic-in-react-hooks),

> `useEffect` runs the clean up and the new effect before moving to the
> next component (depth) first and doing the same.

This means that children components will have there `useEffect` ran first, followed by its parent, which explains why the `useEffect` in `index.tsx` executes before `app.tsx`. This is because `app.tsx` can be seen as a container encompassing the whole app, making it the parent of any other component.

However, a possible workaround to `control` the order of a useEffect, is only by skipping a `useEffect` on first render by using a flag, further explained [here](https://nikolamargit.dev/skip-useeffect-hook-on-first-render/#:%7E:text=The%20most%20straightforward%20way%20is,using%20useRef%20to%20achieve%20this.&text=Let%27s%20break%20it%20down%20line,and%20set%20it%20to%20false.).

```js
const notInitialRender = useRef(false)
useEffect(() => {
  if (notInitialRender.current) {
    document.title = `Current count is ${count}`
  } else {
    notInitialRender.current = true
  }
}, [count])
```